# Linux variable expansion problem ？

Tags: linux, shell

I'd like to get a sequence of number like this 01,02,..,30
But if I use {01..30}, I will get 1,2,..30, the zero before single-digit number is missing. 
How can I get the format like 01,02..30 ?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash4, your `{01..30}` brace expansion actually works as you want it to.  If you are on Bash3 or lower you can use the `printf` builtin along with the brace expansion to get what you want without resorting to external commands.

```
$ printf "%02d " {1..20}
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: always better to use built-ins when available. didn't know Bash4, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
seq -w 1 30  # ought to work
```

as in:

```
for number in $(seq -w 1 30); do
 touch /tmp/bleah$number.dat
done
```